# wsHttpBinding on the wcf service and web reference on the client don't work

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, wshttpbinding, soapheader

I am using `wsHttpBinding` with a WCF service.

I've added a web reference and I've got the web proxy (it is based on `SoapHttpClientProtocol`).

Also I've tried to build a proxy using `wsdl.exe` and the actual wsdl generated by the wcf service (http://zzzz/zz.svc?wsdl).

When the client calls the service, I get the following error:

`The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/Service1/Operation1'.`

Why doesn't the client (the web proxy) work with my WCF service?

What steps should I take to make them work?

I am running .NET FW 3.5 and ASP.NET 2.0.

Comment: Can you check your wsdl SoapAction address

Comment: Here is my WSDL:  <wsdl:operation name="Operation1">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/Operation1" message="tns:IService1_Operation1_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/Operation1Response" message="tns:IService1_Operation1_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
...  
  <wsdl:binding name="httpEndpoint" type="tns:IService1">
  <wsdl:operation name="Operation1">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/Operation1" style="document" />

Comment: the definitioins are:   
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"  xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"  xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy"  
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract"  xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"  xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"  xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"  
The policy:  <wsaw:UsingAddressing />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot consume service exposed on `wsHttpBinding` with default configuration by old ASMX proxy. You must either use *add service reference* / svcutil or change your binding to `basicHttpBinding`. Default configuration of `wsHttpBinding` uses advanced security and ASMX doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank You very much for quick and coherent answer! Hope it helps anyone who made the same mistake...

Comment: I've changed binding to basicHttpBinding, but now I get the following:
System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 415: Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/Operation1"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. I use SOAPUI 4.0 to test the service. WCFTestClient works fine with the service, but the ASMX proxy doesn't. But I need to use web (ASMX) proxy...

Comment: It says you that you are passing request in SOAP 1.2 but the service accepts only SOAP 1.1.

Comment: OK. So how can I change client for it to use SOAP 1.1?
Here is my server configuration:
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService1">

Comment: Delete your proxy and add web reference again. `BasicHttpBinding` uses only SOAP 1.1 so the client should use it automatically.

Comment: @Max: why do you want to use "Add Web Reference" at all? Just use "Add Service Reference", and you get to use any WCF binding you like.