# My WCF service won't use my wsHttpBinding

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wcf-binding

serviceModel section of my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="default" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        textEncoding="utf-8"  useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="templateMgr">
      <endpoint address="http://edocengine.localtest.me/services/templateMgr.svc"
         name="templateMgr.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ItemplateMgr"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"
     aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that I've specified `wsHttpBinding` here, and a large `MaxReceivedMessageSize`. Yet when I breakpoint in the code

```
? System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints(0).Binding.Name
"BasicHttpBinding"
? ctype(System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints(0).Binding,System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding).MaxReceivedMessageSize
65536
```

What gives?

**EDIT**: This is obviously the server web.config. My client is referencing the service with an old fashioned SOAP web service (wsdl.exe proxy) rather than a WCF service reference (svcutil.exe). Therefore the client has no serviceModel section in its app.config. Here are the headers being sent when the client makes a call:

```
POST http://edocengine.localtest.me/services/templateMgr.svc HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.18052)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.edocbuilder.com/ItemplateMgr/setAssets"
Host: edocengine.localtest.me
Content-Length: 12192
Expect: 100-continue
```

EDIT: found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649928/864696), revised the title.

Comment: What happens when you disable the mex?

Comment: There is no `mex` in my web.config. If it's on by default, how do I disable it?

Comment: Try disabling the behaviors and see what happens. It looks like for whatever reason it is referring to something else.

Comment: I commented out `<behaviors>...</behaviors>` and ran the test again. No change. Still coming in as `BasicHttpBinding`.

Comment: Is there Endpoints(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered elsewhere on SE:

> [You cannot consume service exposed on wsHttpBinding with default
>   configuration by old ASMX proxy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649928/864696) You must either use add service
>   reference / svcutil or change your binding to basicHttpBinding.
>   Default configuration of wsHttpBinding uses advanced security and ASMX
>   doesn't support it.

So, I guess I need to go back to basicHttpBinding and make that work.